# (invalid_grant) Missing code verifier google-ads-api

Tags: google-ads-api

As [OAuth Web Application Flow](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/wiki/OAuth-Web-Application-Flow) suggested.

The callback url is like

`https://xxxxxxx:9431/callback_gg/?state=OV8xxxxxx0Nda6B4xxdR6VtAcyBEH&code=4/pAFG4kRxxxx9qLR7Oaxe1-2LYClj7d1EvP7peblfpm5TMEragm1X0Knrs9yLRekxxxxxUC2EcXne_14A4&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords`

I'm tring with

```py
#If the client opted to allow you to access their account, you will
#receive an authorization code in the response as a query string. 
#This #can be used to retrieve an access and refresh token with the
#following #lines of code
flow.fetch_token(code=auth_code)
credentials = flow.credentials
```

But I et error

```
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidGrantError: (invalid_grant) Missing code verifier.
```

Do I miss something? I'm confused with this error for I'm following api doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message implies that you need to add a `code_challenge` request parameter and a `code_challenge_method=S256` request parameter to your authorization request, and add a `code_verifier` request parameter to your token request.

The parameters are defined in [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) (Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients). See [this article](https://www.authlete.com/developers/pkce/) for technical details about RFC 7636.

Google's document is not up-to-date, or the error message itself is wrong and misleading if you see the same error although you include a `code_verifier` in your token request.